# Is it possible to get a simplified expression for the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

$N>M$ where both are natural numbers. $\mathbf{E}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times M}$ is another matrix with orthonormal columns, i.e. $\mathbf{E}^{\text{H}}\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{I}$.

$\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ is another Hermitian symmetric, positive definite matrix.

Now is it possible to simplify the expression $\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{E}^{\text{H}}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{E}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{E}^{\text{H}}$, at least to reduce the number of $\mathbf{E}$? Also, I have the hunch that this matrix is singular, but cannot really get around to prove it.

Comment: what's the number of a matrix? besides I think the right notation for matrices is $M_{n,m}(\mathbb{C})$ or  $M_(n,m,\mathbb{C})$

Comment: Number of $\mathbf{E}$ means simply its occurrences, cancelling out the inverses somehow. That is what I mean by simplification.

Comment: ok then mine is the one. Yours would be something like the cartesian product of $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension NxM. Still you didn't explain what the number of a matrix is. Do you mean the number of times E appears in the expression?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean.

Comment: As the matrix are invertible, $E(E^HAE)^{-1}E^H=E(E^{-1}A^{-1}E^{-H})E^H=A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The rule for invertible matrices is that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ then $(E^tAE)^{-1}=E^{-1}A^{-1}(E^t)^{-1}$ and
$$E(E^tAE)^{-1}E^t=(EE^{-1})A^{-1}((E^t)^{-1}E^t)=A^{-1}$$
because the matrices product is associative.

Comment: $\mathbf{E}$ is not invertible, not even square.

Comment: the tranpose of E is its inverse or E isn't orthonormal. You're right about the dimension of E but the problem is in the text because E is necessarily square. The contraddiction is in the very question

Comment: Why is E "necessarily square"? E.g. if $E=(1,0)^H$ and $A=I_2$, then $E(E^HAE)^{-1}E^H=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ is well-defined and it is not equal to $A^{-1}$.

Comment: because E is the inverse of itself.. more generally any invertible (both on the right and the left) matrix is square

Comment: @NicolòRuggeri Hmm, but that's not what the OP says. The given condition here is that $E^HE=I$, so that $E$ has a left inverse, but that doesn't make $E$ right-invertible. E.g. in my previous comment, where $E=(1,0)^H$, we do have $E^HE=1=I_1$, but $E$, being a non-square matrix, is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks all for participation. I realise my use of the term orthonormal was not appropriate. The condition $\mathbf{E}^{\text{H}}\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{I}_M$ holds, where $\mathbf{I}_M$ is the $M\times M$ identity matrix. However, obviously $\mathbf{EE}^{\text{H}}\neq\mathbf{I}_N$

Comment: @user1551 yes but the definition of orthonormal matrix is that its inverse is its transpose , then it's invertible